# Overriding WebJar assets in Play 2.x

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, playframework, playframework-2.0, less, webjars

Just wonder, if there is a way to override some assets, precisely JS and LESS files, in a [WebJars](http://www.webjars.org/) asset with the ones located in the `app/assets/` directory.

Say, I have a [bootstrap 3.1.1 webjar](https://github.com/webjars/bootstrap) installed, so how do I use my own `variables.less` file for example? Suppose simply putting it in the `stylesheets` folder would not work.

For LESS, maybe it's possible to import them from within my assets, but what about the others?

Answer (score 1):

The `conf/routes` file is priority ordered.  So if you want to override a route just put it higher in the list.  For instance:

```
GET     /webjars/bootstrap/3.1.1/less/variables.less   controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", "my-bootstrap/variables.less")
GET     /webjars/*file                                 controllers.WebJarAssets.at(file)
```

Comment: Well, that's right, but less files aren't served directly, in my case they're compiled down to `bootstrap.min.css`.

Comment: In Play 2.3 you should be able to do this with the new `sbt-web` asset pipeline.  But currently there isn't a way to do what you want with WebJars since WebJars aren't part of the asset compiler process.

Comment: Hence, the only option I'm left with, is to put an WebJar asset content in my `app/assets` directory, at least until 2.3 is released?

Comment: Well, personally I'd find another way to modify the UI.  I think it is usually a bad idea to modify upstream library source code.  In the case of Bootstrap can you instead override styles in a less file of your own?

Comment: Yes, I can. But the point that one small change would require moving the whole webjar content into `app` folder. I'm just get used to Ruby on Rails approach on overloading gem contents.

Comment: I think that will be easy with the new sbt-web stuff.